# How can I create schema for give collections for given?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

I want to make MongoDb food website schema. I have three collections

1. hotels

Hotel has these fields `name, delivery_time, delivery_fees, slug, title, etc other`

2. categories

Categories has these `name, or id`

3. items

How I use linking between them 
    item has these fields `name, price,rating, hotel_id, or etc others`

How can I create a scheme for these table also for users and order?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through [Mongoose Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) to learn how to create DB Schema.

For example purpose,i can show to how to do it. But, you need to customize it according to your need.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var hotelSchema = new Schema({
  name:  String,
  delivery_time: String,//you can keep this as Date Type also, depends on your requirement
  delivery_fee: Number,
  slug: String,
  title : String //Add other fields according to your requirement.
});
```

Go through above doc, and try to create schema for yourself. If  you face any issue while doing that, then you should ask questions on Stack Overflow.

**References in MongoDB:**

For Adding `reference` of one `collection` in other `collection`, you can use `mongoose populate`. Please go through [Mongoose Populate Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for better understanding.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks ravi but can you please me the collection references because i search a lot but con't find the relation about each other. i did worked a lot in mysql but there is joins.

Comment: I have added references for you,and edited my answer accordingly. Please go through it.

Comment: ok thank for reply bro it helps, but one thing i have to know what type of i use mean (Reference or Embedded). kindly help me about this also.

Comment: i think you should go for `references` for your usecase. And if this answer helped you , please accept it by clicking the right tick.